# Sharepoint List's Custom Field value appears empty in ssrs report when run in sharepoint integrated mode

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services, custom-field-types, integrated-mode

I have a sharepoint list that contains custom field(its is developed as .wsp solution), its a file upload control and two rendering templates 'display' and 'edit' templates are defined. 'Display' template displays url of file uploaded using the custom field as ASP Hyperlink.

Template is an .ascx control and its code is as follows:

[image]

Then I created .rdl report using report builder to display the Hyperlink field's url attribute value in one of the columns. SSRS report displays the custom field's Hyperlink's url attribute value without a problem.

But problem lies in displaying the hyperlink url attribute value when the same SSRS report is uploaded in share point server Under "Site Assets" Folder inside one of the "Site Collection" that already exists there. Hyperlink Url attribute value is not displayed(all custom field controls related values appears blank). I have used CAML Query(using query designer in ssrs report builder tool) to query the list of Client Details from the sharepoint list(it contains fileupload control details including other text fields)

I am not sure if CAML Query is fully working when the SSRS report built using Report Builder is deployed and run inside sharepoint server. The CAML Query generated to run in SSRS report is copied below:

[image]

In above Query 'All_x0020_Citizenship' is the reference to file 'upload field control' in Sharepoint list mentioned at the beginning. Does this problem has to do with CAML Query?Is the CAML query has to be different to run under sharepoint server through sharepoint report service?

May be i need to change custom control code to be rendered which is complaint with sharepoint report service integrated mode? If so please provide some idea on how program custom control code such that its value can be displayed correctly in ssrs report in sharepoint server.

My Sharepoint List's AddItem.aspx page view looks as follows:

[image]

Please look into the issue and shed some lights on how to find a solution or alternatives to display hyperlink field value in ssrs report in sharepoint integrated mode.

Hope you'd let me know if any part of my post is unclear to you so that i can explain further to clarify any confusion on my post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.